# git commit specific staged deleted file

Tags: git, git-commit

I removed a file from my git repo (`git rm a`) and made a change to another file (`b`). I also have a bunch of other changes lying around, but I want to specifically commit those two in one commit and deal with the rest later. My status is basically:

```
# Changes to be commited:
#    deleted:   a
#    renamed:   f1 --> f2
#    renamed:   g1 --> g2
#    ... other irrelevant stuff ...
#
# Changed but not updated:
#    modified:  b
#    modified:  h
#    modified:  .. other files ..
#
```

I want to do:

```
git commit a b -m "..."
```

That does work ("error: pathspec 'a' did not match any file(s) known to git"). I know I can do `git commit -a` to commit the delete itself, but I don't want to commit everything, I want this one commit to be *just* the changes to `b` and the removal of `a`. How do I do that?

Comment: Think you can only do it by staging only the stuff you want to commit. i.e. first reset your index, then add the 2 changes, then commit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can reset the HEAD and index by running `git reset --mixed`. Then you should have all of your changes (including the deletion) unstaged.

Then run `git add -u <fileYouDeleted>` and then your deleted file will be staged (but the others will not). Then you can commit just the deletion.